# Formula works in conditional formatting but not in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The formula in the code below works when I use it in conditional formatting but not in VBA :

```vb
Sub setCondFormat()
    Range("P69").Select
    With Range("P69:P10000")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
          "=AND($P69>$S69;$B69<>$B70:$B241;$I69<>"")"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = -6052865
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I already tried changing `;` to `,` and it didn't work. I also deleted `$` but that didn't work either.

When I used only this formula it worked:
`=$P69>$S69`

When I deleted `=` it worked but then I have this formula in conditional formatting: 
`="AND($P69>$S69;$B69<>$B70:$B241;$I69<>"")"` and of course that doesn't work

I have English version.

Do you please know what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, i wrote that i already tried it and nothing

Comment: What does `$B69<>$B70:$B241` mean? What are you trying to achieve? Can you paste a picture of what you have in Conditional Formatting?

Comment: It means that if it's same value in range B70:B241 like it's in cell B69 then cell P69 will be not colour

Comment: Do you mean this one ? [picture](https://imgur.com/K6SfVUy)

Comment: You should try avoid using `.Select()`

Comment: There is one really weird error after i run vba, formatting doesn't work well but if i check formula (and change nothing) and then i apply it, after that it's working well. Do you know where can be problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the quotation marks in the last part of the formula: `$I69<>""`. You have to escape them by doubling:

```vb
Formula1:= "=AND($P69>$S69,$B69<>$B70:$B241,$I69<>"""")"
```

I would also suggest that as a beginner, you could try using the macro recorder to see the code behind your UI actions, like in this case.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks. I tried macro recorder, but for conditional formating it's not working or i do something wrong. One more time thanks a lot